# timer doesn't show minutes

Tags: android, android-activity, timer

I'm trying to set a timer. the timer is working but it counts only seconds ... the minutes remain 00.

```
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long millis = ((System.currentTimeMillis() + resumeTime) - startTime);
        int hours   = (int) ((millis / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
        int seconds = (int) ((millis / 1000) % 60); 
        int minutes = seconds / 60;

        TextView timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        timer.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hours, minutes, seconds));

        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As WarrenFaith suggested seconds is always between 0 and 59, dividing it by 60 just means that it is always 0.

So to get minutes,Change

```
int minutes = seconds / 60;
```

to

```
int minutes = (int) (millis / (1000 * 60));
```

Comment: @Alona Happy to help,enjoy coding.

Answer (score 1):

`seconds` is always between 0 and 59, dividing it by `60` just means that it is always 0. You should modify your math to get the minutes based on `hours` and not `seconds`. Doing the math is up to you :)

PS: I just read that your question title contradicts the first sentence of your question. Yu mean your minutes is always 00 and not the seconds, right?!